# How to get the time elapsed from a json date?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, datetime

I am using jquery ajax($.ajax) method to get a json object from c# webmethod.This json object contains a datetime value, which looks something like this '/Date(1329324492302)/' and I tried to parse it using the following js

```
new Date(parseInt(json.d.Date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10))
```

and the resulting date looks something like this

`Date {Wed Feb 15 2012 16:48:12 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}`

I want to find the time elapsed from this datetime to current time in javascript but I am not sure how to do it,as the parsed date looks like a string instead of a date.

Could someone please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = {d:{Date:"/Date(1329324492302)/"}};

var date1 = new Date(parseInt(json.d.Date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
var date2 = new Date();

var diff = (date2-date1);  // 

var hours = Math.floor( diff / 3600000);
var minutes = Math.floor( (diff % 3600000) / 60000);
var seconds = Math.floor( ((diff % 3600000) % 60000) / 1000);

console.log(" elapsed " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
//timestamp from json
var startTime = parseInt(json.d.Date.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10))
//current timestamp
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
//difference in milliseconds
var diff = endTime - startTime;
```

Comment: well, if its on the same day I could do var endTime = new Date().getTime(); How should I deal with it if it is a different day?

Comment: @kranthi `getTime()` gets you the number of milliseconds since unix epoch - not the time of day. So `diff` is the difference in milliseconds from one point in time to the other. Doesn't matter if it's on another day or in another year - it's just a number of milliseconds