# Countup from set date and time

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that, when you click start patrolling, starts counting the time since you clicked the button. Because I need to store this on the server (ASP.NET) and because I want to resume the count when they reload the page, I get two variables from the server. The first variable is the server time they clicked the start patrolling button. The second variable is the offset of the local time from the server time so we are 100% exact on the amount of time and it isn't off because of the local time. The following code works but the hours are WAY off. Currently the local time is 19:53 and if this function runs it starts at "18:00:00" and then goes up "18:00:01", "18:00:02" etc... If the local time was 20:53 it would be "19:00:00". Why is this function doing this and how can I correct this?

**patroltimeCurrentTimeoffset** is the returned offset value (EG: -729)

**patroltimeStart** is the date and time the on the server that the user started patrolling (EG: April 10, 2012 20:01:13)

```
function UpdatePatrolTime() {
        var patroltimeCurrentTime = new Date();

        patroltimeCurrentTime.setTime(patroltimeCurrentTime.getTime() + patroltimeCurrentTimeoffset);

        var patroltimeStarted = new Date(patroltimeStart);
        var CompareDateTime = new Date((patroltimeCurrentTime.getTime()-patroltimeStarted.getTime()));

        currentHours = CompareDateTime.getHours();
        currentMinutes = CompareDateTime.getMinutes();
        currentSeconds = CompareDateTime.getSeconds();

        currentHours = (currentHours < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentHours;
        currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
        currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;

        var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds

        document.getElementById("patroltime").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
    }
```

And the <span> control:

```
<span id="patroltime">00:00:00</span>
```

Comment: Not a specific solution, but I'd suggest using a standard like UTC or something for all date manipulation.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement that soon. No major hurry on this one because this is for a local company's application and not for the entire internet.

Comment: @GabrielGraves— *patroltimeCurrentTimeoffset* must be in milliseconds, and where does *patroltimeStart* come from? It too should be a number in milliseconds, not a date string (unless you manually parse the date string to create a date object).

Comment: I do manually parse my date string because the database has an actual start date time (which is what I need to store in the database) and not just a milliseconds representation. The offset works correctly so that wouldn't be the problem. See my answer for my solution and I will award points if you can find the reason for my change or explanation for the old code not being right that I've quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from "**[How to get the time elapsed from a json date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297974/how-to-get-the-time-elapsed-from-a-json-date)**" but if anybody is able to figure out why my solution above doesn't work (so I can award someone points for explaining for me and possibly others) I will award them the points. My solution was to change the following code:

```
    var patroltimeStarted = new Date(patroltimeStart);
    var CompareDateTime = new Date((patroltimeCurrentTime.getTime()-patroltimeStarted.getTime()));

    currentHours = CompareDateTime.getHours();
    currentMinutes = CompareDateTime.getMinutes();
    currentSeconds = CompareDateTime.getSeconds();
```

to

```
    var patroltimeStarted = new Date(patroltimeStart);
    var diff = (patroltimeCurrentTime-patroltimeStarted);

    currentHours = Math.floor(diff / 3600000);
    currentMinutes = Math.floor((diff % 3600000) / 60000);
    currentSeconds = Math.floor(((diff % 3600000) % 60000) / 1000);
```